# How to count and show all information with php using while loop?

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

I'm trying to show all information from my mysql database using while loop, of course I could do this without while loop, but I want to show this information organized in html divs.

```
$cnt = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM `reviews`"));
echo $cnt;
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cnt)) {
    echo '<div class="panel panel-default">
    '.$Row['name'], $Row['text'].'
    </div>';
}
```

Whats bad in my code, how I can fix it to make it work?

Comment: You need to fetch the result of `mysqli_query` not `mysqli_num_rows`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch the associative array on the query, not the count.

```
$q = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM `reviews`");
$cnt = mysqli_num_rows($q);
echo $cnt;
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) 
{
    echo '<div class="panel panel-default">
    '.$Row['name'], $Row['text'].'
    </div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a valid resource from mysql and you get that from `mysqli_query` with `mysql_num_rows` you get the number of rows in your table but no resource.

```
$res = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM `reviews`");
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo '<div class="panel panel-default">
    '.$Row['name'], $Row['text'].'
    </div>';
}
```

So if you rewmore the `mysqli_num_rows` command it should work if your connection is correct.

Comment: `echo $cnt;` should be `echo mysqli_num_rows($cnt);`.